# jquery - drag/drop an image from desktop and make it resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to make a simple page where I can drag/drop an image from desktop and make it resizable inside div. I can drag, drop and resize an image that is already defined inside the page, but once I upload it from desktop, it is not resizable.  Here is my code.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">

      <style>
    .draggable {
        width: 150px; 
        height: 150px; 
        padding: 0.5em; 
        float:left; /* important */
        position:relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */

    }
    div#droppable {
        border: 5px dashed #CCC;
        width:400px;
        font-family:Verdana;
    }

    }
    div#droppable li img {
        height: 30px;
    }

      </style>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>
    $( function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({


            // Find original position of dragged image.
            start: function(event, ui) {

                // Show start dragged position of image.
                var Startpos = $(this).position();
                $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
            },

            // Find position where image is dropped.
            stop: function(event, ui) {

                // Show dropped position.
                var Stoppos = $(this).position();
                $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
            }
        });


        $('#droppable').on({
            'dragover dragenter': function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            },
            'drop': function(e, ui) {
                //console.log(e.originalEvent instanceof DragEvent);
                var dataTransfer =  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                if( dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files.length) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $.each( dataTransfer.files, function(i, file) { 
                      var reader = new FileReader();
                      reader.onload = $.proxy(function(file, $fileList, event) {
                        var img = file.type.match('image.*') ? "<img  id=\"resizable\" src='" + event.target.result + "' /> " : "";
                        $fileList.prepend( $("<span>").append( img + file.name ) );
                      }, this, file, $("#fileList"));
                      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    });
                }
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );  
            }
        });

    });


      $( function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                height = $("#resizable").height(); 
                width = $("#resizable").width(); 
                console.log("width=height="+ width +"=="+ height);
            } 
        });
      } );


      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    table {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
        background-position: top;
    }
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
      #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    </style> 


     <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
      <!--img src="imgs/pic.jpg" id="resizable"/-->
      <div id="fileList"></div>
      Drop file here.
    </div>

    <div id="start">Waiting for dragging the image get started...</div>
    <div id="stop">Waiting image getting dropped...</div>


    <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

     <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="position: absolute; left: 285px; top: 267px;">
      <p>me, too</p>
    </div>

    <!--div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>Drop here</p>
    </div-->


    </body>
    </html>
```

Is it because I dynamically upload an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute `$( "#resizable" ).resizable();` after image loading and after having added new `img` element to the DOM:

```
reader.onload = $.proxy(function (file, $fileList, event) {
    var img = file.type.match('image.*') ? "<img  id=\"resizable\" src='" + event.target.result + "' /> " : "";
    $fileList.prepend($("<span>").append(img + file.name));
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
}, this, file, $("#fileList"));
```

Check my fiddle for a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/g73p7skk/